# How do I use a function on individual variables in a collection of objects

Tags: c#, function, reflection

I'm looking for a way to apply a function to a collection of objects each with multiple variables of the same time such that I can apply the function to each of the objects in the collection and select which of the variables I want to apply it to. For example: 
take the class

```
point{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
}
```

Now let's say that I wish to apply the function "flatten" to a list of these points such that one of it's variables becomes 0.

Where flatten might be something like:

```
   flatten<variableName>(List<Point> points){
          foreach(var point in points){
             point.<variableName> = 0;
          }
   }
```

Does anybody know if this is possible with c#, maybe using some kind of reflection like structure? I know it can be done in Javascript and I was hoping to do this in c# as it would prevent a lot of duplicate code (note the real function I want to use this for is far larger and contains multiple sub functions).

Comment: I suspect this has been asked before, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Do you expect `variableName` to be part of method's name or can you pass it as a parameter?

Comment: How about a function that takes a delegate

Comment: @StepTNT variableName  can be passed as a parameter

Comment: How about a function that takes a delegate. `IEnumerabke<TItem> flatten<TItem, TValue>(List<TItem> items, Func<TItem, TValue, TItem> propertySetter, TValue newValue) { return items.Select((i) =>  propertySetter(p, newValue));}`

Comment: @Dave yes now that does look like a good option for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your mock code expects someone to pass a variable name why not just pass a lambda instead:

```
void Flatten(List<Point> points, Action<Point> action)
{
  foreach(var point in points)
  {
    action(point);
  }
}
```

So now you can say:

```
Flatten(points, point => point.x = 0);
```

If you want to set more than one valuethen pass an expression block:

```
Flatten(points, point =>
{
  point.x = 0;
  point.y = 0;
});
```

If you're interested in working with sequences other that `List` (HashSet, for example) then just change `Flatten` to use an `IEnumerable`:

```
void Flatten(IEnumerable<Point> points, Action<Point> action)
{
  foreach(var point in points)
  {
    action(point);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm that looks interesting, I guess I could apply 1 to get and one to set the variables and use that to apply the function correctly.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same as `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)`? Isn't the whole point of the question that `Flatten` should capture the logic, and a property should be provided?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - as I pointed out at the end of the answer, you may want to do this for any `IEnumerable`. The `ForEach` method only exists on `List`.

Answer (score 2):

While I like Sean's solution more, as it's closer to C# and doesn't require reflection, a possible response to the exact question of the OP could be this one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    internal class Point
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y;
        public int Z;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"({X}, {Y}, {Z})";
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Flatten(string name, IEnumerable<Point> points)
        {
            // Get either fields or properties
            var memberInfo = typeof(Point)
                .GetMembers()
                .Where(m => m is FieldInfo || m is PropertyInfo)
                .First(m => m.Name == name);

            // Set target value
            switch (memberInfo)
            {
                case FieldInfo fieldInfo:
                    foreach (var point in points) fieldInfo.SetValue(point, 0);
                    break;
                case PropertyInfo propertyInfo:
                    foreach (var point in points) propertyInfo.SetValue(point, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var points = new List<Point>
            {
                new Point
                {
                    X = 10,
                    Y = 20,
                    Z = 30
                },
                new Point
                {
                    X = 100,
                    Y = 200,
                    Z = 300
                }
            };

            Console.WriteLine($"BEFORE: {string.Join("; ", points)}");

            Flatten(nameof(Point.X), points);

            Console.WriteLine($"AFTER: {string.Join("; ", points)}");

            Console.WriteLine("------------------");

            Console.WriteLine($"BEFORE: {string.Join("; ", points)}");

            Flatten(nameof(Point.Y), points);

            Console.WriteLine($"AFTER: {string.Join("; ", points)}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> BEFORE: (10, 20, 30); (100, 200, 300)
>
> AFTER: (0, 20, 30); (0, 200, 300)
>
> ---
>
> BEFORE: (0, 20, 30); (0, 200, 300)
>
> AFTER: (0, 0, 30); (0, 0, 300)

EDIT:
improved the code to deal with both fields and properties.

Comment: This won't work in the values are fields rather than properties, as they are in the posters question.